# Inno Setup: Run command after installation

Tags: windows, shell, installation, command, inno-setup

I need my Inno setup installation to run a program when the installation of my application has finished.

The program I need to run can can be executed with this command:

```
C:\Path\To\Application\MyProgram.exe -c componentA -i C:\Path\To\Application\MyFile.bin
```

I can then go to the Window's registry to check if *MyProgram.exe* was successfully doing its purpose.

So in my Inno Setup Compiler .iss-file I have this setup:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Files\For\Installation\MyProgram.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Files\For\Installation\MyFile.bin"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags ignoreversion
```

When the installation is done, I see *MyProgram.exe* and *MyFile.bin* have been placed where the application was installed:

```
C:\Path\To\Application\MyProgram.exe
C:\Path\To\Application\MyFile.bin
```

I have setup my Inno Setup script to run the the program with the parameters like this:

```
Filename: "{app}\MyProgram.exe"; Parameters: "-c componentA -i {app}\MyFile.bin";
```

My intension was the this would have the installation to run:

```
C:\Path\To\Application\MyProgram.exe -c componentA -i C:\Path\To\Application\MyFile.bin
```

When running the installation I see the Window's terminal is opened and immediately closed. I assume the installation at least is trying to run what I want. But I'm unable to see any information displayed in the Window's terminal due to it's immediately closed.
When checking the Window's registry nothing has been altered = No success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My first guess would be that the application was installed to a path with space (like `Program Files`), so you need to escape the path in the parameters: `Parameters: "-c componentA -i ""{app}\MyFile.bin""";`

Comment: I added the /K switch but it was unable to let the window's terminal remain open.

I also installed the application at C:\MyApplicaiton but with no success.

Comment: Show us your new entry.

Comment: Filename: "{app}\Myprogram.exe"; Parameters: "/K -c componentA -i ""{app}\MyFile.bin""";

Comment: That's not what my answer to the linked question shows. Please read it again carefuly. You have to use `{cmd}`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what I'm miss:
I used:
Parameters: "/K {app}\setup.bat arguments"
To:
Parameters: "/K -c componentA -i {app}\MyFile.bin"
Then included escape to the path:
Parameters: "/K -c componentA -i ""{app}\MyFile.bin"""

Comment: `Filename:  {cmd}; Parameters: "/K ""{app}\MyProgram.exe"" -c componentA -i ""{app}\MyFile.bin"""`

Comment: Thanks Martin! I now see that that it apparently cannot find MyProgram.exe. I will try to debug this now. Apparently the {app}don't point to the correct path.